# Prevent Stylelint from enforcing an alphabetical order on vendor prefixes?

Tags: lint, stylelint

Is it possible to apply a flag to prevent Stylelint from enforcing an alphabetical order on vendor prefixes? I have a declaration order that I'm pleased with in my config, but my vendor prefixes are automatically generated through Autoprefixer within a gulp task on my SASS files. However I want to lint the final CSS file on the fly using Circle CI, so the CLI is perfect for that.

The issue is that by the time the file is being linted, Autoprefixer has added vendor prefixes in a non-alphabetical order, and I receive warnings and the automated tests fail. I cannot see a way to dictate the order that autoprefixer provides vendor prefixes, and these are the only warnings being thrown on my CSS at this point.

The docs clearly state `Prefixed properties must always be alphabetically ordered and must always precede the unprefixed version`. but is there a way around this within the config?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new feature request, not really a technical question. As you've pointed out, the tool is behaving as documented. So please file an issue with stylelint articulating your idea!

Comment: Correct. For further discussion, this issue exists https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/1087